# Problem with Algolia search, when product contains bracket in name

Tags: magento, algolia

I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong with my Algolia search functionality in Magento 1.

I have a product with the name: Huawei P Smart (2019).
When I'm trying to find it by regular search (no autocomplete) with phrase **p smart 2019**
I have an empty result.

But when I search it as **p smart (2019)** then I have a correct result.

Request for **p smart 2019**:

```
{"requests":[{"indexName":"magento_default_products","params":"query: p smart 2019
hitsPerPage: 40
maxValuesPerFacet: 40
page: 0
ruleContexts: ["magento_filters",""]
facets: ["categories_without_path","price.EUR.default","color"]
tagFilters: "}]}
```

And response:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "hits":[

         ],
         "nbHits":0,
         "page":0,
         "nbPages":0,
         "hitsPerPage":40,
         "facets":{

         },
         "exhaustiveFacetsCount":true,
         "exhaustiveNbHits":true,
         "query":" 2019",
         "params":"query=p%20smart%202019&hitsPerPage=40&maxValuesPerFacet=40&page=0&ruleContexts=%5B%22magento_filters%22%2C%22%22%5D&facets=%5B%22categories_without_path%22%2C%22price.EUR.default%22%2C%22color%22%5D&tagFilters=&filters=&numericFilters=visibility_search%3D1&facetFilters=%5B%22categories_without_path%3Ap+smart%22%5D&query=+2019",
         "index":"magento_default_products",
         "processingTimeMS":1
      }
   ]
}
```

What I see in response, is this query = **-2019** (- is space here) like it try to match word by word, am I right?

When I'm trying to search by **2019** or **-2019** (- is space here) then I have correct results.

My configuration is almost the default one for Magento and Algolia.

Is someone who had a similar issue? Or maybe know where I should look for fix it?